# Differences in mobile web application frameworks

Tags: cordova, mobile, sencha-touch, appcelerator, jqtouch

I am going through different web application frameworks for mobile devices. 
 I have found frameworks like PhoneGap/Appcelarator/Rhomobile (I am calling these as group1) And SenchaTouch/JQTouch/JqueryMobile(I am calling these as group2)
I would like to know at high level how group1 frameworks different from group2 frameworks. Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I know, we can not compare group 2 and group 1. If u want to create pure mobile web, u can do it by using group 2 only, without using group 1. But, if u want to convert mobile web to be native apps, u must use group 1 + group 2.

Answer (score 1):

HI. Well group 1 as you stated

are sort of shelled environment. These are containers of html/javascript code that allows that html-centric app to be used natively on the target mobile device.

However, group2 are framework that usually create html pages that you can use as mobile site.. Jquery mobile on its own can be used to create a simple mobile website and you don't need to install it on the mobile device..

but use phonegap with jquery mobile and you will be able to get your html-centric app to run natively thanks to phonegap.

Give it try.

Answer (score 0):

this question has been asked quite a bit in this very forum. I would suggest just querying SO and you will find many references to blog postings and documentation to help you find what is the best tool for your specific requirements.